# I can not call javascript in acsx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to call javascript in acsx page in asp.net.i am using one if condition and call up javascript.But it is not working?following is my code

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if (diff <= 0)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onload", "display();", true);
    }
}
```

Its not working

I tried Response.write also ,its not working

anybody can tell me the solution for this

Comment: Please check whether condition `if (diff <= 0)` is getting true.

Answer (score 0):

How do you decide whether its working or not? Did you get any java-script error?

You should check the view source in browser and check if the corresponding script (`display();`) has been emitted (towards the end of source) or not. If is has then obviously the quoted piece of code has worked. The issue might be that the corresponding function definition (`display`) might be missing or there is some other java-script error - enable java-script debugging in the browser to troubleshoot.

If the script let has not been emitted then you need to check if your conditional is getting executed or not - which can be easily done using server side debugging (F5) in visual studio. If `RegisterStartupScript` line is getting executed and still you don't see the script in view source then issue could be that the script key that you are using for registration (`"onload"`) might have already been used in the user control somewhere else - so try using different key. For example,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "on-start-display", 
    "display();", true);
```